# On the review panel I cannot see, where the documentation proposal is belonging to

Tags: feature-request, documentation

In the review panel sometimes it is hard to approve, because I didn't know which tag/topic it is belonging to. Maybe a sort of breadcrump navigation can help (Tag->topic->...), so each reviewer can check also the context of this review.

Comment: If you see this again, please add a screenshot and browser/OS details.

Comment: Our designers are looking into some changes to the review pages. The breadcrumb you suggested is on their list to add.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it belongs to which topic see the image below
[image: Documentation change]  You can see the marked part and it tells it belongs to which tag and which title is changed or added and also the changes are highlighted (removed text with red, added text with green)

Comment: I didn't see any of this in a particular review, or at least I don't remember. It has vanished even I didn't skipped it.

Comment: this is the document review tab. can you see this?

Comment: Currently the document review tab is empty for me,  I will take a screenshot next time I see this issue.